# how to declare a function as a type with mandatory parameter

Tags: typescript

I declare a type which is a function which take one parameter of type Person and return a Person.

I didn't specify that the parameter is optional, then why does typescript allow me to pass him a function without parameter ?

```
type Patcher = (key: Person) => Person;

function doSomething<T>(patcher: Patcher){
   console.log('hello world');
}

doSomething<Person>(() => { // Here I pass empty parameter but typescript doesn't complain
    console.log('Hello world 2');
    return {
        firstName: 'john',
        age: 10
    }
})


interface Person{
    firstName: string;
    age: number;
}
```

I'm using last typescript version

Comment: It's in the FAQ [Why are functions with fewer parameters assignable to functions that take more parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters)

Comment: This is the way to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51143582/typescript-is-there-a-way-to-typecheck-function-arity. But don't 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript does not yell at you for a good reason.

Would it have made a difference if you were to add a parameter that would have been unused?

```
doSomething<Person>((personThatWouldNotBeUsed) => {
    console.log('Hello world 2');
    return {
        firstName: 'john',
        age: 10
    }
})
```

You saying "I expect a function that takes a `Person` as a parameter, and returns a `Person` as a result" merely means that you will *call* whatever function with a `Person` object, and that you will treat the returned result as a `Person` object. Whether the function actually uses the supplied parameter is completely up to it.

---

TL;DR - You can't force the callback your consumer passes to use all of the parameters, nor should you be able to. It is up to the consumer to decide whether it wants to use the supplied parameter or not.

Comment: Well.. you can concoct a complicated solution using conditional types (I'm 100% sure I have one somewhere on SO but can't find it right now), but you are right, it's not worth it, TS has this right can't think of a good reason to force this.